# CKAN/Vagrant port forwarding

Tags: vagrant, ckan

I created a vagrant box and installed ckan inside of it.

In the vagrantfile - i set up port forwarding to 4567 - so when in my browser i type

```
127.0.0.1:4567
```

I get to ckan inside the virtual box.

The problem is that now - when i do some actions in ckan like update my profile - I get redirected to

```
http://127.0.0.1/user/mirmir
```

which gives me an error of "Not Found - The requested URL /user/mirmir was not found on this server."

If i manually insert the :4567 so it becomes

```
 http://127.0.0.1:4567/user/mirmir
```

everything works.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: This is more like an application issue, something wrong with the redirect. You will be better off using Public Network instead of NAT with port forwarding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably be doing this with a private network: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/private_network.html

Once you have added the IP address into your Vagrantfile like this:

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"
```

You should reload vagrant and be able to browse to 192.168.50.4, there should now be no problems because you will not need to use a port in the URL.